# Check if Count of all Arrays Matches

Tags: c#, arrays, count

Is there an elegant way to check if the `Count` of all `Arrays` matches?

Currently I'm getting the `Count` value of 1 array, and using the value to check against other arrays.

```
int arrayItemCount = array1.Count;

if ((array2.Count != arrayItemCount) || (array3.Count != arrayItemCount))
{
    //do something
}
```

It would also help prevent situations where any of the arrays are `null`.

---

**Edit:**

Rational for checking length of all arrays is for the following requirements:

- There are 8 `string` values delimitered by comma `,`
- The arrays can be `null` or (blank)
- For each value split by `,` delimiter, stop processing if any of the conditions are met:

  1. If number of items in all arrays don't match
  2. If any of the items in all arrays are (blank)
  3. If any of the items in the arrays are 'Error'

  Sample Data:

> ```
> NameArray: new string[] {'Tom','Mary','Jerry'};
> AgeArray: new string[] {'10','11','12'};
> GenderArray: new string[] {'male','Error'};
> ```

- If any sample above, there are 2 records that will not be processed:

1. `GenderArray` contains 'Error', so `Mary`'s record will not be processed.
2. `GenderArray` contains only 2 values, so `Jerry`'s record will not be processed.

Only `Tom`'s record will be processed.

Comment: Why do you have variables that end with numbers?  Usually variables with number endings make good candidates for arrays themselves.  It's fine to have an array of arrays.  i.e. instead of `array1`, `array2`... you could have `array[0]`, `array[1]`, etc.

Comment: Can you please share with us why do you need to compare the arrays' length?

Comment: @PeterCsala I have updated my reason for comparing arrays' lengtj

Comment: @gymcode For this simple use case I would not complicate my life. I would use that simple comparison that you just showed. Please bear prefer to use `.Length` property instead of `.Count()` method if possible.

Comment: It really looks like you need a custom class to hold the name, age, and gender together and then just one array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all your arrays in a nested array:

```
int[][] allArrays = new int[][] { array1, array2, array3, array4 };
```

Then you can use LINQ to group your arrays by the count. If there is only one group, all arrays have the same count:

```
var groups = allArrays.GroupBy(x => x.Length);
if(groups.Count() == 1)
{
  Console.WriteLine("all arrays have the same count");
}
```

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AT945q (with a list containing all arrays, but the principle is the same)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ can make the code more succinct here, as it can in many situations. There are multiple possibilities, e.g.

```cs
if (allArrays.All(arr => arr.Length == allArays[0].Length))
```

or:

```cs
if (allArrays.Select(arr => arr.Length).Distinct().Count() == 1)
```

`allArrays` would be a list of some sort containing all your existing arrays.

Answer (score 1):

May be we will try to solve the *original problem*? Given

```
var NameArray   = new string[] {  "Tom",  "Mary", "Jerry" };
var AgeArray    = new string[] {   "10",    "11",    "12" };
var GenderArray = new string[] { "male", "Error",         };
```

We can put ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KlpFtT)):

```
using System.Linq;

...

var result = (NameArray ?? Array.Empty<string>())
  .Zip((AgeArray ?? Array.Empty<string>()), 
       (n, a) => (name : n, age : a)) 
  .Zip((GenderArray ?? Array.Empty<string>()), 
       (p, g) => (gender : g, name : p.name, age : p.age)) 
  .Where(item => item.age != "Error" && item.name != "Error" && item.gender != "Error")
  .ToArray();
```

Let's have a look:

```
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);

Console.Write(report);
```

Output:

```
(male, Tom, 10)
```

Please, note that `Zip` will trim arrays for you